# Difference between Java GSON and Flutter json_annotation causes error

Tags: json, flutter, serialization, dart

I'm trying to use Flutter/Dart to communicate with a Java Netty server. I am using Gson on the Java side and json_annotation and/or manually serialize JSON methods on the Flutter side. They both use UTF8. The problem is I use this syntax:

```
{
  "ENCRYPT": false, // to use to check if the packet is encrypted
  "jsonObject": {} // The packet class. This gets encrypted if it ENCRYPT = true
  "packetIdentifier": "" // Name of packet so it can be deserialized correctly
}
```

Problem is, GSON and Flutter serialization have different results which cause errors on both sides.

GSON InitialPacket example [codec here](https://github.com/Fernthedev/light-chat/tree/master/java/core/src/main/java/com/github/fernthedev/core/encryption/codecs/gson) [packet here](https://github.com/Fernthedev/light-chat/blob/master/java/core/src/main/java/com/github/fernthedev/core/packets/handshake/InitialHandshakePacket.java):

```
{
  "ENCRYPT": false,
  "jsonObject": "{\"versionData\":{\"version\":\"1.5.3\",\"minVersion\":\"1.5.3\"}}",
  "packetIdentifier": "INITIAL_HANDSHAKE_PACKET"
}
```

Flutter InitialPacket example [codec here](https://github.com/Fernthedev/light-chat/blob/master/flutter/lib/backend/transport/codecs/codecs.dart) [packet here](https://github.com/Fernthedev/light-chat/blob/1d508a8aa1cef64bf117af33e9b76bfc5121941c/flutter/lib/backend/packets/handshake_packets.dart#L14-L51):

```
{
 "ENCRYPT": false,
 "jsonObject": {
   "versionData": {
     "version": "1.5.3",
     "minVersion": "1.5.3"
    }
  },
 "packetIdentifier": "INITIAL_HANDSHAKE_PACKET"
}
```

What is the best solution I could use so both results are the same?
To test, I've been running the Java server and the Flutter app and connecting to the Java server from the Flutter app. As of writing this, there are debug logs on both sides to see what is written, received and when errors occur the JSON string is shown. The server jar is built using `gradle clean build` in the `java` directory and the jar is found in `java/server/build/libs/` and is just `server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Note: I removed the publicKey field from the examples above since it is randomly generated and 4096 bits long, making it harder to read.

Comment: You've apparently encoded the `jsonObject` twice. First the `versionData` map must be being encoded to a string, then included in packet map and then that gets json encoded. Just do the same in Dart. When decoding in Dart, decode the packet map to obtain the `jsonObject` and then decode that.

Answer (score 0):

> [@Richard Heap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9597706/richard-heap) You've apparently encoded the jsonObject twice. First the versionData map must be being encoded to a string, then included in packet map and then that gets json encoded. Just do the same in Dart. When decoding in Dart, decode the packet map to obtain the jsonObject and then decode that.

Yep that was the solution. Thank you :)